# How to get rid of Chrome's 'Continue browsing' link without visiting it?

Tags: chrome-for-android, offline

There is [no sensible way](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1428393) to get rid of Android Chrome's 'Continue browsing' link when it appears, if one does not wish to visit the site in question again. Are there any workarounds?

[image: cont. Br.]

(In our above example image we show Wikimedia's Upload Wizard site page as the site that we don't want to visit again.)

Answer (score 0):

Go offline. Now, yes, tap the 'Continue browsing' link to  "visit the site" (safely offline). You will get a choice where you can finally **cancel** the pending future visit.

[image: cancel button]